# How to detect if there's any certificates renewed by `certbot renew`?

Tags: bash, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I want to automatically renew SSL certificates provided by let's encrypt.

Here's my plan:

1. Use crontab to execute `certbot renew` everyday.
2. If there's any certificate renewed by `certbot renew`, use AWS CLI to upload the certificate to a load balancer. (AWS China doesn't have Certificate Manager yet, that's why I use let's encrypt.)

My problem is that I don't know how to detect if there's any certificate renewed by `certbot renew` command.

This command returns something like the following:

```
*** renew ***
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/ooo.com-0001.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/xxx.com-0002.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert not yet due for renewal

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/ooo.com-0001/fullchain.pem expires on 2019-12-25 (skipped)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com-0002/fullchain.pem expires on 2019-12-25 (skipped)
No renewals were attempted.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
same
```

I think it would be difficult to parse the string to decide if there's any renewed certificates.

Comment: Never parse output not designed to be parsed from the first place. Look at the `--deploy-hook` option of "renew": "Command to be run in a shell once for each
                        successfully issued certificate."  Besides that your question if offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: My deploy hook script cannot be found by `--deploy-hook`. This is so strange. It says `Running deploy-hook command: /etc/upload-cert/main.sh
Hook command "/etc/upload-cert/main.sh" returned error code 127
Error output from main.sh:
/bin/sh: /etc/upload-cert/main.sh: not found`

I've confirmed that `/etc/upload-cert/main.sh` file exist.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#renewal ? It has extensive discussion on using hooks after renewal. Your error can also come because of permissions: who owns the script (and its parent directories), under which user does certbot runs and in which context (crontab, etc. and hence various $PATH and so on)

Comment: How did you eventually solve this, using a hook or something else?